# conversion for cmd line to int console c++

Tags: c++, .net, c++-cli

I am trying to convert cmd line input into an integer using C++. The compiler tells me it doesn't recognize my string? Can someone shed some light?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>
#pragma hdrstop

using namespace System;

int main()
{

    Console::WriteLine("Enter a num");
    string g = Console::ReadLine();
    int gi = Int32::Parse(g);
    Console::WriteLine(gi);
    Console::ReadLine();
    Console::ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: Uh, what is the input that you're providing? And what is the exact error message that the compiler (are you sure it's the compiler?) is giving you?

Comment: That looks like C++/CLI, not really C++. You'll probably get better answers if you fix the tagging (I'd fix it myself, but I'm not entirely certain whether it's really C++/CLI, or perhaps the older Managed C++, or possibly the newer C++/Cx).

Comment: Cody, the input coming in through the cmd should be an integer.

Comment: The error msg I get are:

Comment: Error 3 error C2065: 'g' : undeclared identifier \copyToClipBoard.cpp 14
Error 1 error C2065: 'string' : undeclared identifier a 14
Error 2 error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'g' 14

Comment: use `std::string`, not `string`

Comment: Error 2 error C2665: 'System::Int32::Parse' : none of the 4 overloads could convert all the argument types

Comment: Ah, you don't want `string` at all, you want `String`. Not sure what header it comes from, but it should not be `#include <string>`

Comment: It seems you totally mixed up `c++` and `c++-cli`. I think, you should decide first, what language do you use, and tell us

Answer (score 2):

Use String^ and Int32^ - managed classes. If you have Intelisense it should help you

```
#include "stdafx.h"

using namespace System;

int main(array ^args)
{
    Console::WriteLine(L"Enter a number:");
    String^ inputStr = Console::ReadLine();
    Int32^ number = Int32::Parse(inputStr);

    Console::WriteLine(number);

    Console::ReadLine();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Error 2 error C2665: 'System::Int32::Parse' : none of the 4 overloads could convert all the argument types